# ifelse returning NAs when condition is true

Tags: r

I am missing something fundamental here. I want to extract strigns from a dataframe based on nested `ifelse`

**Input**

```
library(stringr)
vec1<-c("1cm start shaped area Barr.","small tongue of columnar lines mucosa in the.")

vec1<-data.frame(vec1,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Attempt**

```
ifelse(grepl("Barr|column",vec1$vec1),str_extract(vec1$vec1,"\\d\\s*cm.*Barr|column\\?//."),
           ifelse(grepl("Barr|column",vec1$vec1),str_extract(vec1$vec1,"tongue.*col"),"No"))
```

**Desired output**

```
"1cm start shaped area Barr"
"tongue of col"
```

**Actual output**

```
[1] "1cm start shaped area Barr" NA
```

Why are the two conditions not being met and extracted?

I will go on to use case_when with `dplyr` as an alternative I guess but I'd like to understand the problem with the `ifelse` (and why `case_when` might be different to `ifelse`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first condition (which is weirdly identical to the second I think?) is `TRUE` for both elements, but the extraction of the first pattern is `NA` for the second element:

```r
library(stringr)
vec1 <- c("1cm start shaped area Barr.","small tongue of columnar lines mucosa in the.")

vec1 <- data.frame(vec1,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

grepl("Barr|column", vec1$vec1)
#> [1] TRUE TRUE
str_extract(vec1$vec1, "\\d\\s*cm.*Barr|column\\?//.")
#> [1] "1cm start shaped area Barr" NA
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

You could of course instead give a vector for the pattern argument of `str_extract()` if your two `ifelse()` conditions are indeed **supposed** to be identical:

```r
library(stringr)
vec1 <- c("1cm start shaped area Barr.","small tongue of columnar lines mucosa in the.")

vec1 <- data.frame(vec1,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

grepl("Barr|column", vec1$vec1)
#> [1] TRUE TRUE
str_extract(vec1$vec1, "\\d\\s*cm.*Barr|column\\?//.")
#> [1] "1cm start shaped area Barr" NA
ifelse(grepl("Barr|column", vec1$vec1),
       str_extract(vec1$vec1, c("\\d\\s*cm.*Barr|column\\?//.", "tongue.*col")),
       "No")
#> [1] "1cm start shaped area Barr" "tongue of col"
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. I think I needed to ifelse if the sentence matched but the pattern returned NA, but your solution works great. Thanks